# How to add output parameter using sh

Tags: python, shell, sh

I have this Python script:

```py
"""
Get a monitor's details returns "OK" response
"""
from datadog_api_client import ApiClient, Configuration
from datadog_api_client.v1.api.monitors_api import MonitorsApi

id = int(input("Write the monitor ID: "))
configuration = Configuration()
with ApiClient(configuration) as api_client:
    api_instance = MonitorsApi(api_client)
    response = api_instance.get_monitor(
        monitor_id=id,
    )

    print("Type:",response["type"])
    print("Name:",response["name"])
    print("State:",response["overall_state"])
```

How do I add a .sh script on linux that passes the `monitor_id`?

Comment: Passing an argument to a python script from a sh script seems a bit redundant to me. Why not using environment variables or python arguments instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.sh file

```
python3 test.py arg1 arg2 arg3
```

.py file

```
import sys
arguments = sys.argv[1:]
print(arguments)
# ['arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3']
```